# How to get instance of nested relationship in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have `User` model,
*has many morph* `Notification`. The `Notification` model also *belongs to one* `NotificationType`. I want to find data from `NotificationType` through the `User` instance. Here is the relationship code:

```
// User.php
public function notifications()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Notification::class, 'notifiable');
}

// Notification.php
public function notification_type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(NotificationType::class, 'notification_type_id');
}
```

This is the code I have tried:

```
$notificationType = $user->notifications()->notification_type()->where('name', $this->data->type)->first();
```

But, it returns

> staging.ERROR: Call to undefined method
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany::notification_type()
> {"userId":"996cdaea-c6f3-444a-a430-036e1966ab91","exception":"[object]
> (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Call to undefined method
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany::notification_type()`

Is it possible to get the notification_type directly from the `$user`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've tried all your suggestions, but they don't seem to be working. With the first one, it will do the where() on the users table, not the notification_types table. And the second one, it throws an error because User model doesn't have the notification_type() method.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but sorry, I think you misunderstood my question. I want to get the notification_type data, not the user data.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just found the solution. Since the `$user->notifications()` is the instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany`, there is a function to get the instance of the `Notification` model, that is `getRelated()`. I found it [here](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphMany.html).

Since I got the `Notification` model class, I finally can retrieve the `notification_type()` relation method.

Here is my fixed code:

```
$notificationType = $user->notifications()->getRelated()->notification_type()->getRelated()->where('name', $this->data['type'])->first();
```

I am open to any suggestions to improve or fix the code above. Thank you.